# How to draw polygon background with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have the page which is full of content.

There is a polygon which I want to set as a background for the whole page with color #E0E6E5.

```
polygon(0 0, 100% 35%, 100% 65%, 0% 100%)
```

How can I do this?

I know that it sounds very simple.
But I was unable to do it with clip-path which basically cuts off the other half of the page and makes is non-visible.
A static image is not an option.

Is there any other option that I am missing?

Comment: just in case, take a look at this: https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/ there is a lot of shapes made in css.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The shape you want is this:

```css
.box {
 -webkit-clip-path:polygon(0 0, 100% 35%, 100% 65%, 0% 100%);
 clip-path:polygon(0 0, 100% 35%, 100% 65%, 0% 100%);
 width:200px;
 height:200px;
 background:#E0E6E5;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

You can easily do it with gradient and multiple background:

```css
.box {
 width:200px;
 height:200px;
 background:
   linear-gradient(to bottom left,transparent 49.8%,#E0E6E5 50%) top   /100% 35%,
   linear-gradient(to top    left,transparent 49.8%,#E0E6E5 50%) bottom/100% 35%,
   linear-gradient(#E0E6E5,#E0E6E5) center/100% 30%;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: I've made the same thing with clip-path but it cut off the white part of the whole page. The 2nd sample with gradients works perfectly! Thank you very much.